# Setting a message from the string in Office365 Graph API

Tags: rest, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am looking into sending an email using Graph API that was prepared by using external library (e.g. Zend Mail). For example, for [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) the process would be following:

- convert the message to a string
- do base64 encoding
- call setRaw() on message

I am reading [Office 365 documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message) but this Message resource does not seem to have such method. Is it still possible to be done in a similar manner?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.  Graph doesn't provide such API. You can submit an feature request in the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Currently, you can convert the message from external library to JSON string but not pure string. And use the JSON string as the request body of Graph API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I guess my best bet would be to create it on my own. A bit strange that no one had this idea before, I can't find anything alike.